# How to get data id instead of UUID in Menu picker swiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, menu

Im trying to get sort id which is coming from my server . I can get UUID for each sort type in menu picker but how can I get their id instead of UUID  when I select a sort type in Menu.As you can see in my code I can get UUID with Just(selection) but I need to get sort id which is data.id .

```
 @State private var selection = UUID()
@Binding var sortClicked : Bool
@ObservedObject var productListViewModel = ProductListViewModel()
var sortListArray : [ProductListSortAndFilterList]


var body : some View {
    
    HStack(alignment: .center){
        
        Spacer()
        
        Picker(selection: $selection, label: SortView().frame(height:UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.050), content: {
            ForEach(sortListArray, id: \.uid, content: { item in
                
                if item.id == "sort" {
                    
                    ForEach(item.sortList ?? [],id:\.uid) { data in
                        
                        Text(data.name ?? "")
                            .tag(data.id)
                            
                           
                    }
                    .onReceive(Just(selection)) { (value) in
                        
                        print(value)
                        
                    }
                    
                }
            })
        })
        .pickerStyle(MenuPickerStyle())
        .padding()
        .background(Color(.systemBackground).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))
        .cornerRadius(5)
```

Comment: why not use selection as id instead of UUID(which you get from the server)? also you can find the id from array using array.firstIndex(where...)

Comment: I tried to use selection = " " and give id :\.id instead of uid but then its not triggered when sort selected in menu I don't know why.

Comment: what is the type of  "data.id"?

Comment: data.id is string